# Get Min Value From a nested dict

Tags: python-3.x

on Python 3.7 I have a dict:

```
my_dict={
  "rows": [
    {
      "name": "AAAAA",
      "ariseTime": 1568395916000,
      "key": "MMS",
      "value": 21.0,
      "tooltipValue": "21.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "AAAAA",
      "ariseTime": 1568395944000,
      "key": "MMS",
      "value": 20.0,
      "tooltipValue": "20.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "AAAAA",
      "ariseTime": 1568396177000,
      "key": "MMS",
      "value": 19.0,
      "tooltipValue": "19.0"
    },

  ],
  "total": 4017,
  "yaxis": [

  ]
}
```

I have to find the Minimum value which should be 19 here

I've try:

```
def Find_min_est(est_dict):
        v = min(est_dict.keys(), key=lambda x: est_dict['rows'][x]['value'])
        return v
```

But the error return is:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Could someone help me ? I'm just start learning Python recently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you got is dues to the line `v = min(est_dict.keys(), key=lambda x: est_dict['rows'][x]['value'])`. The `keys()` will return a list `["rows","total","yaxis"]`. Then for every entry in this list you are trying to do `est_dict['rows'][x]['value']`. `est['rows']` is a list and `est_dict['rows'][x]` is trying to access element of that list where `x` is a string.

What you need is to iterate over `my_dict["rows"]` (if I get you correctly). Then you need to change the code a bit. Like -

```
def Find_min_est(est_dict):
        v = min(est_dict['rows'], key=lambda x: x['value'])
        return v['value']
```

The iterable in this case will be the list (my_dict['rows']). So, the lambda will get individual element of that list (which is a dict). Returning the value of `value` field will do the job. But the min will return an element of that list and not the desired value and hence the `v['value']` part in return

Another approach will be to call `min()` over a generator expression like -

```
def Find_min_est(est_dict):
    return min(e['value'] for e in est_dict["rows"])
```

Both of this solution assumes that every element of that list contains a value for the key `value`. You may want to add some check for the existence if that is not the case.